# Map from block of xml

Tags: map, xml

I have response xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xmldata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" status="SUCCESS">
  <recordset name="res" nritems="2">
    <record name="order" id="777">
      <field name="restorant">Black</field>
      <field name="location">West 44</field>
      <field name="ordercount">10</field>
    </record>
    <record name="order" id="888">
      <field name="restorant">Green</field>
      <field name="location">East 55</field>
      <field name="ordercount">20</field>
    </record>
    <record name="order" id="999">
      <field name="restorant">Yellow</field>
      <field name="location">East 99</field>
      <field name="ordercount">40</field>
    </record>
  </recordset>
</xmldata>
```

I am trying to do Map with

**KEY** - location

**VALUE** - whole this block (for every record - based on key location)

```
    <record name="order" id="999">
      <field name="restorant">Yellow</field>
      <field name="location">East 99</field>
      <field name="ordercount">40</field>
    </record>
```

in MAP-it is necessary to follow the same order as in XML.

I am trying to get this value but can take only value from the last block and can not get whole block for further parsing.

```
DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(responseBody);

for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNode : document.getRootElement()
                    .getChildElement('recordset', null)
                    .getChildElements()) {
    for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNodeInternal : xmlNode.getChildElements()) {
        if (xmlNodeInternal.getAttribute('name', '') == parseField) {
            returnValue = xmlNodeInternal.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: As a general note, Maps (and sets) do not have an order. If you need things to be in a predictable order, then you need to use a `List` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a map of maps to hold above data

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> ...
```

But it's perhaps easier to make an inner class:

```
class XMLRecord {
  //should be restaurant btw
  String restorant;
  String location;
  Integer ordercount;
}

Map<String,XMLRecord> recordMap = new Map<String,XMLRecord>();
```

Then load the doc as before:

```
DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(responseBody);


for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNode : document.getRootElement()
        .getChildElement('recordset', null)
        .getChildElements()) {
        
    String recordId = xmlNode.getAttribute('id');
    XMLRecord xmlRec = new XMLRecord();

    for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNodeInternal : xmlNode.getChildElements()) {
        String name xmlNodeInternal.getAttribute('name')();
        String value xmlNodeInternal.getText();
        System.debug(name + ' ' + value);
        if (name == 'restorant'){
          xmlRec.restorant = value;
        }
        if (name == 'location'){
          xmlRec.location = value;
        }
        if (name == 'location'){
          xmlRec.location = value;
        }
    }
    
    recordMap.put(recordId,xmlRec);
}
```

The diff is just in the storage of the record id and examining the values to see what attribute they should be assigned to.

If this was a `Map` you wouldn't have to do that, but extracting them would be messier. It's really a value call here.

Comment: I created separate class XMLRecord. It doesn't work String recordId = xmlNode.getAttribute('id');
. thx for help